# What is wrong with my htaccess subdomain rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess

I want to rewrite www.domain.com/s/index.php?s=test into test.domain.com

I did it successfully in local host using the following.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.localhost$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /s/index.php?s=%1 [L]
```

However, when i put it live on my server, it didnt work. below is the code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /s/index.php?s=%1 [L]
```

What went wrong? Appreciate advices.

Comment: What error did you get (if you got one)?

Comment: there is no error, when i go to test.domain.com it just display domain.com when it should display content from www.domain.com/s/index.php?s=test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thorough research, there is no mistake in the above htaccess code i posted. Error occurs because there is a conflicting statement.